# Why is my App within my Emulator not starting?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

> Process: org.wit.assignment, PID: 13760
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.wit.assignment/org.wit.activities.PlacemarkActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.wit.activities.PlacemarkActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.wit.assignment-ODvCPFcDKOvLMtR6CUhbbw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.wit.assignment-ODvCPFcDKOvLMtR6CUhbbw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.wit.activities.PlacemarkActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.wit.assignment-ODvCPFcDKOvLMtR6CUhbbw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.wit.assignment-ODvCPFcDKOvLMtR6CUhbbw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
> at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1243)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)

This is the error code I get when starting up my App, I just created 2 packages within my org.wit.assignment package, one for activities and one for the model which is org.wit.assignment.activities and org.wit.assignment.models with classes inside each. Would anyone have any idea why it's giving me this error saying it cannot find class ''org.wit.activies.PlacemarkActivity'' when it's within the activities package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your manifest file and see there if your activity has new package name in their

Comment: Oh wow that was it too... Did it say the issue happened within the manifest file in the error anywhere as I didn't see any mention of it.

Comment: No it didn't say it but reading this part java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.wit.activities.PlacemarkActivity clicked me where the issue could had occurred